# "No value given for one or more required parameters." Error when trying to delete record

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I see there are a lot of these questions, but I still can't figure my error from looking at them. I am trying to delete a record from my table in Access. Here is the code:

//method to delete record
        public static void DeleteProject(Project aProject)
        {

```
        {
            String sSQLProjectDeleteCommand = "Delete * from Project where JobNo=" + aProject.JobNo;


            // Create the command object
            if (aConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                aConnection.Open();

            OleDbCommand Cmd = aConnection.CreateCommand();
            //Delete project
            Cmd.CommandText = sSQLProjectDeleteCommand;
            // Execute the SQL command
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            aConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

I am using 3 layer architecture and the error occurs at "Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't `DELETE * FROM` you `DELETE FROM`

Remove the `*` and it should work.

--

**Update**: Also, if `JobNo` is a string, you should add quotes to the parameter:

```
String sSQLProjectDeleteCommand = "Delete * from Project where JobNo='" + aProject.JobNo + "'";
```

This would be better done with a parameter though:

```
String sSQLProjectDeleteCommand = "Delete * from Project where JobNo=?";
...
Cmd.Parameters.Add(aProject.JobNo);
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Update 2**: modified parameters since OleDbCommand doesn't allow named parameters, it seems

Comment: that worked! Thanks a lot, JobNo was a string variable because it was formatted "J####" and I was basing my code off an example from my class, but I didn't realize in that example the ID was an int.